# Subversion: Failed to Check in [PowerBuilder]

Tags: svn, powerbuilder

I am using PowerBuilder 12.5, Tortoise SVN 1.8, Wandisco 1.8 and PBSCC Proxy in my Windows 7 ultimate 32 bit no service pack. But, my files are failing to check in but, I can check them out.

Here is my log:

```
Checking out selected items...
Successfully checked out C:\Inventory Count\inventory.pbl(dw_branchloc.srd) version 2
Operation Completed
Checking in selected items...
Failed to check in C:\Inventory Count\dw_branchloc.srd
Operation Completed
```

Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: You can activate the PBSCC log to get more information: add/change the value of `HKLM\Software\FM2i\PBSCC Proxy\log.path` string value (on a 64bit system it will be `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\FM2i\PBSCC Proxy\log.path`) to a valid filename (it will be created if needed) and try again the check-in. There should have some info in the log file.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed that issue by giving write permission over the Project folder. Make sure you have permission to write over there.